# iPhone UI Design for Navigation Controller - buttons moving down

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller, ui-design

I created a navigation controller based app. The view that opens up below the nvigation bar has a UIImageView and a bunch of 'detail disclosure' buttons on top of te uiimage for navigation purposes as well.

What I am noticing is that these buttons s have deviated down from their designer (interface builder) position when they come up in the simulator.

I suspect the navigation bar has something to do with it, but they don't move down proportional to the height of the navigation bar.

I am not sure how to tell them to hold on to their position.

The UIImage does not overflow the height of the screen even with the navigaion bar at the top.

Are their any guidelines/gotchas one needs to know about when using navigation bar at the top?

I am using xcode 4

Thanks

**Edit:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    StartScreenViewController *controller = 
    [[StartScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartScreenViewController" bundle:nil];
    _navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    _navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 460);
    _navigationController.title = @"Test";
    //[self.window addSubview:_navigationController.view];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Another thing is that if I use the 'addsubview' method then the nav bar is truncated while if I assign the nav controller to window.rootviewcontroller then I see the whole nav bar.

**Edit 2**

Here how my AppDelegate.h looks

```
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

//@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Here is the AppDelegate.m's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
StartScreenViewController *controller = [[StartScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartScreenViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    navController.title = @"Test";
    navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    [self.mainView addSubview:navController.view];    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The MainWindow.xib contains App delegate and the window as the objects. the Window has a UIView underneath it.

StartScreenViewcontroller's xib file has the UIImageview and the buttons.

Comment: What you used at top default navigation bar or image ?

Comment: navigation bar, the usual, nothing fancy

Comment: Is _navigationController an IBOutlet? If so, change that. And it won't need to be global (AFAIK) because each ViewController loaded into it can access it with self.navigationController.

Comment: I will give that a try. _navigationController variable was created as part of the navigation project setup. I appreciate your time and help steve. I will report back.

Comment: Steve, I tried that it did not work quite as I had expected. Earlier I had a nav bar with a title set on it. Once I removed the IBOutlet declaration, some how the nav bar became half the size with no title. Do you have an example showing a simple navigation controller example with an imageview as part of the view?

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer below. If you have any issues with it I can probably post the test project to github.

Comment: Steve, Thanks again. I did the steps you have outlined. Now the Navbar shows up fully but with no title, in spite of setting it explicitly in the appdelegate.m. Also the "detail disclosure" buttons still move down.

Comment: You can set the title in StartScreenViewController in viewDidLoad like this: [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"My Title"];

Comment: The difference between what you are doing and what I am doing is small but may be the problem. I created a new View-based project. Therefore the StartScreenViewController, for example, would actually be defined in IB. I've made another update below to show my AppDelegate.h file.

Comment: If you create a new project you'll see how they setup the MainWindow.xib file for you with the ViewController as an object in the Documents window of the xib.

Comment: Steve, thanks again. I am still missing something. The buttons still move down. I have uploaded my view based app to github. This might help us figure out what I am missing quicker. https://github.com/klimaye/NavigationControllerTest

Comment: I ran your project and the buttons aren't moving. The background image is actually being vertically resized which may be causing the appearance of your buttons moving. I'm still investigating...

Comment: Ok the resizing thing was due to your Autosizing properties in IB. Open ViewBasedAppTestViewController.xib. Select the ImageView for Test2.png. In the Attributes window, go to View Size then Autosizing. Change the outside marks to only be top and left and remove all inside marks. I did this and ran it in the simulator and it looks identical to the xib file now, minus the Nav Controller of course.

Comment: Steve, Thanks a bunch. Being new to iphone world, did not have a clue about this. I should have played around more with those properties in hindsight. I just saw the different behavior the moment I added the nav bar. Sorry for the trouble. Thanks again!!!!.

Comment: So, why did this not occur when I simply had no nav bar. So the thing to learn from this would be to anchor any imageviews to top left when using a nav bar?

Comment: It's probably because the iPhone tries to be smart and automatically handle certain things like moving and resizing for you when you add a Nav Controller. Unfortunately it's not always right.

Comment: I wouldn't say that anchoring ImageViews like that should be a steadfast rule. The problem was that you had it anchoring to all 4 sides and then stretching vertically and horizontally as well. Those Autosizing options can be tricky. After you set them if you hover over the animation to the right you can see the effect that the different settings have. Also try rotating the View in IB with the icon in the top right of the View window and this will show you the effects of your changes in a real world scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some screen shots and see how far they are being moved down. If its 20px then this is a problem that tons of people have had (including myself). I fixed it by redefining the view to be the same size that it is in IB. For some reason the iPhone tries to be smart and help you resize things and sometimes it does it wrong.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
                navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];
```

If that doesn't work then try this search: [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Biphone%5D+20px](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Biphone%5D%2020px).

EDIT:
I missed a piece here. In order to get around this I had to add a UIView to the MainWindow.xib file....
1. In your AppDelegate.h, create a property for IBOutlet UIView *mainView
2. Do the @property thing for it and synthesize it in the .m file 
3. Open MainWindow.xib
4. Drag a UIView onto the Window (NOT the ViewController) and make it fit the full frame
5. Right click the AppDelegate object in the Documents window in IB and connect the mainView property to the UIView you just added.
6. Now in AppDelegate.m...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

    //[self.window addSubview:navController.view]; // old broken way
    [mainView addSubview:navController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

and AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface TestNavigationAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    TestNavigationAppViewController *viewController;
    IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet TestNavigationAppViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. Do you as a rule start with a View based app and add navigation instead of starting with a navigation based app?

Comment: Steve, the above did not work. Curiously, the view in IB is 320X460 (in xcode 4). I will look at the link you mentioned for more incite. Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that the buttons are moving down 20px? If not, then this may not be your problem. I do typically start with a View based app and add the navigation to it.

Comment: When you tried the code above, I assume you were in your App Delegate in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions? If you could update your post and show me where you are adding the nav stuff I could help you troubleshoot a little better.